# A sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is strictly increasing. Is its range compact? Explain why or why not.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> A sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is strictly increasing. Is its range compact? Explain why or why not.

I have a few ideas, but I can't come up with a formal proof.

Since the sequence is strictly increasing, it does not converge to anything.

For the range to be compact, the range must be closed and bounded. For the range to be bounded, the sequence must also be bounded..

Thanks!

Comment: You can't conclude that it is not bounded. Indeed, $1- (1/n)$ is strictly increasing and bounded above by $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is not correct, since $1-\frac1n$ is a strictly increasing sequence that is bounded (so, you incorrectly inferred that if the sequence is strictly increasing, it is not bounded).

However, your proof is correct for the case if the sequence does not have an upper bound.

So, you just have to prove that the range is not compact even if the sequence is bounded. For that:

**Hint**:

If an increasing sequence is bounded, then it converges.

- Since it is strictly increasing, can it ever reach its limit?
- Can you use this to prove the range is not closed?

Comment: Since it is striclty increasing, it will never reach it's limit. And if it doesn't reach it's limit, the limit is not included in the range and therefore the range is not closed...?

Comment: @mathinthecity And that's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly increasing doesn't mean unbounded; consider, for instance
$$
x_n=\frac{n}{n+1}
$$

If the sequence is unbounded, its range is not compact. If it is bounded, it may be or not depending on whether the range is …

> closed. However the range cannot be closed because its supremum is the limit of the sequence and, since the sequence is *strictly* increasing, the supremum cannot belong to the range.

Comment: Thanks! 
So for the range to be bounded the sequence has to be bounded. 
If so sequence has to bounded and has a least upper bound say b 
then the sequence converges to b and the range is (-oo, b) which is not compact. Also x.n cannot be equal to b for any n, for if it were then x.n would not be strictly increasing. 
^Would this be a better solution?

Comment: @mathinthecity Compact means *closed* and bounded. Can the range be closed?

Comment: @mathinthecity The range is not $(-\infty, b)$. It's just a small subset of this set. The range is $$\{x_1,x_2,x_3\dots\}$$ and this set is clearly not equal to $(-\infty, b)$.

Comment: The range can never be compact.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Right so.

Answer (score 0):

$tan^{-1}x$ is bounded but not compact, it is also strictly increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1. If $\{x_n\}$ is not bounded then as you say the range is not compact.
2. If $\{x_n\}$ is bounded, it is converging. Check if $\lim x_n$ belongs to the range and conclude whether the latter is compact or not.